# Why does sshd accept syscall have inconsistent behavior in Linux audit framework across versions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, system-calls, audit

The audit daemon seems to have trouble catching accept events from sshd on my Ubuntu 14 VM. I set up an audit rule for accept system calls. I then run auditd and notice that I do not get events for the accept call. However, if I then restart sshd I will then start getting the events in auditd when I try to ssh into the box.

Complicating the puzzle is that I've tried this with a couple of different kernels and seen the same behavior on both. I've also tried it with a couple of different versions of auditd. I also tried it on Ubuntu 16, but the behavior does not occur there with auditd. I'll put all the details below.

I found [a thread on the mailing list](https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2015-January/msg00060.html) about a similar issue, but that solution does not seem to be the answer here. Any help, suggestions, or insight is appreciated. Thanks.

---

I ran all my VMs in VirtualBox 5.1.10 and used 64-bit machines. For Ubuntu 14 I tested auditd on both the 3.13.0-96 and 4.4.0-47 kernels. On Ubuntu 16 I tested it on 4.4.0-38. This spread on the Ubuntu 14 kernel seems to rule out a change to kauditd being the problem.

I used [auditd](https://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/) 2.4.5 and 2.3.2. On Ubuntu 14 I installed 2.3.2 using apt and built 2.4.5 from source. On Ubuntu 16 I installed 2.4.5 using apt and built 2.3.2 from source. On Ubuntu 14 they both did not receive notification of sshd accept calls until after a restart of the sshd agent, whereas on Ubuntu 16 they both received the notifications without the restart.

Here's the procedure for replicating the issue:

1. Start the VM
2. Install auditd via apt or from source
3. Restart the VM
4. `sudo auditctl -l` should show there aren't any rules
5. `sudo auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S accept`
6. `sudo auditctl -l` should now show the accept rule
7. `sudo auditd -f`
8. Attempt to ssh into the VM

You should see accept (`syscall=43`) events on Ubuntu 16, but not Ubuntu 14. To see the events in audit on Ubuntu 14, restart the ssh daemon:

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

Comment: I also asked [the auditd mailing list](https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2016-December/msg00011.html) about this issue.

Comment: Looks like it's a [kernel issue](https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2016-December/msg00037.html).